# Accessing properties file dynamically in springs

Tags: spring-mvc

We are developing a java web application using Spring MVC with JSON at my presentation layer.
For displaying the UI labels in JSP instead of hard-cording we are getting it from the properties file and in the JSP represent we are using  **spring:message** tag. We are using **ResourceBundleMessageSource** to achieve this.This is working fine.

But our application will be accessed from various region and based on the region we have different properties file for UI labels which needs to be used. Keys in all the properties file will be same only the value will be diffrent.

For eg: Say there are 2 reqions 'Region1' & 'Region2' from where the application will be accessed by the user, i have 2 properties file such as message_region1.properties & message_region2.properties. Now when the user log in from Region1 i need to pick message_Region1.properties and if the user log-in from 'Region2' i need to pick message_Region2.properties and display the UI labels. Since all the keys in both the properties are same there wont be any changes in my jsp files.

Any advice how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:)
Create your `message_region1.properties` and `message_region2.properties` files. And Spring picks up the appropriate property file depending on the client's locale (using Default `LocaleResolver`). The property files generally are in the format `filename_<language>_<country>.properties`

And if you want to tell the Spring, how the locale should be resolved, use one of the 4 approaches given in [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver)

**EDIT:**

To dynamically change the property file, use one of the below ways; I don't know if they are better than the 4 approaches (mentioned in above spec).

1. Just before returning the view, change the locale to the "unique code" of the logged in user, as below.

   ```
   RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request).setDefault(new Locale("your code"));
   ```
2. Change your message source in spring config to ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

   ```
   <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
       <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </bean>
   ```

   And reset properties file name in controller, before returning the view, as below:

   ```
   messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages" + your code);
   ```

Comment: The region1 & region2 are not country name /code. For example within UK user can access from various business units. So for each business unit we have a unique code/name which we will append to the properties file name. Once the user logs-in we will have the unique code based on which we need to pick the respective properties file for UI labels.

Comment: Edited the answer to suit your need. please check